# Emulate Chrome scrollbar with custom scrollbar - Disable hover event on scrollbar-button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to emulate the Windows Chrome scrollbar with a custom scrollbar.  I am extremely close. All that remains is to stop the hover event on the scrollbar-button when the scrollbar-thumb is up against it.  I already wrote some jquery to change the button image when the thumb is against it so I would think its fairly easy to add in `$(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');` to the `scroll()` function but "this" has to equal `body.scrollbar.up::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement` and I can't figure out how to do that.  This is what I have so far including the unbind and bind statements that I want which have no effect right now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $("body").removeClass("up");
      $(this).bind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    } else {
      $("body").addClass("up");
      $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    }    
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $("body").addClass("down");
       $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    } else {
      $("body").removeClass("down");
      $(this).bind('mouseenter mouseleave')
    }  
  });
});
```

```css
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 17px;
    background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240);
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #a3a3a3;
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background-color: #505050;
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
    display: block;
    height: 17px;
}

/* Up */
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowup.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
body.scrollbar.up::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowupup.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowuphov.jpg);
}

/* Down */
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowdown.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
body.scrollbar.down::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowdowndown.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:single-button:increment:hover {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowdownhov.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="height:1550px;" class="scrollbar up">

<p>Scroll down this page.</p>

<p style="position:fixed;">Scroll the page and see the scrollbar look and function exactly the same as the stock windows version of Chrome scrollbar.  Hover the arrow buttons and see them change.  Now help me kill that hover effect when the scrollbar-thumb is up against the arrow buttons, just like the real chrome scrollbar.</p>

</body>
```

I've also put the code into a [codeply snippet](https://www.codeply.com/p/roznqVoCnJ)

Comment: For the effect, are you talking about how the images are preloaded so there is a brief "flash" while the image loads? Also, have you tried: `$("body.scrollbar.up::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement").bind('mouseenter mouseleave');`?

Comment: I did try that with no success.  I'm not worried about the flash.  If you look at an actual chrome scrollbar, there is no hover effect on the arrow background when the scrollbar thumb is up against the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to add another class `top` for when the scrolling is at the top, and `bottom` when its at the bottom.

Then for the hover css, use `:not(.top)` and `:not(.bottom)` to state only apply that hover when top and bottom aren't applied respectively.

On page load, I also added the appropriate classes if the top or bottom of page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0) {
      $("body").addClass("up top");
}
else if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
  $("body").addClass("down bottom");
}
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $("body").removeClass("up top");
      $(this).bind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    } else {
      $("body").addClass("up top");
      $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    }    
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $("body").addClass("down bottom");
       $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    } else {
      $("body").removeClass("down bottom");
      $(this).bind('mouseenter mouseleave')
    }  
  });
});
```

```css
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 17px;
    background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240);
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #a3a3a3;
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background-color: #505050;
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
    display: block;
    height: 17px;
}

/* Up */
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowup.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
body.scrollbar.up::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowupup.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

body.scrollbar:not(.top)::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowuphov.jpg);
}

/* Down */
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowdown.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
body.scrollbar.down::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowdowndown.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

body.scrollbar:not(.bottom)::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:single-button:increment:hover {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowdownhov.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="height:1550px;" class="scrollbar up">

<p>Scroll down this page.</p>

<p style="position:fixed;">Scroll the page and see the scrollbar look and function exactly the same as the stock windows version of Chrome scrollbar.  Hover the arrow buttons and see them change.  Now help me kill that hover effect when the scrollbar-thumb is up against the arrow buttons, just like the real chrome scrollbar.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Close.  Only works for the down arrow.  And now the up arrow doesn't change when you scroll away from the top.

Comment: @ChrisL I had it working but I added a change in the editor that I didn't think would break it. It seems to be working now

Comment: +1 thats working.  I would still like to see if there is a way to target the scrollbar-button pseudo element in jquery and use the `unbind`.  I'll give it a day or two before I accept this.